# Java, "URI can't be null" error on simple HTTP client

Tags: java, http, uri

I'm trying to write a simple HTTP client that, given an absolute HTTP path, performs a simple HTTP GET request and prints out the content to standard output.

However, I'm getting the following error on any page I try to load:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI can't be null.
    at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:141)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:926)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at HTTrack.main(HTTrack.java:68)
```

The code that is raising the exception is:

```
try
{
    System.out.println("We will attempt to read " + getfilepath(args[0]) + " from " + getbasesite(args[0]));
    URL serverConnect = new URL("http", getbasesite(args[0]), getfilepath(args[0]));
    con = (HttpURLConnection)serverConnect.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");    
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setReadTimeout(10000);
    System.out.println("Attempting to connect to " + getbasesite(args[0]) + " on port 80...");
    System.out.println("URL = " + con.getURL());
    con.connect();
    //System.out.println("Connection succeeded! Attempting to read remote file " + getfilepath(args[0]));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}
```

The line that is raising the exception `(HTTrack.java:68)` is the `con.connect()` line, and the functions `getbasesite` and `getfilepath` return the server host name and remote file paths of a URL, respectively.

For example if passed the string `http://www.somesite.com/somepage.html`, `getbasesite` will return `"www.somesite.com"` and `getfilepath` will return `"/somepage.html"`.  I know the `HttpURLConnection` is being passed these values correctly because when I call `getURL` it returns what I expect: `http://www.somesite.com/somepage.html`

I'm stuck as to what might be causing this error - I've tested that the `HttpURLConnection` class indeed gets the correct URL out of the constructor arguments with the line `System.out.println("URL = " + con.getURL());`, so I'm not sure why it's failing the attempts to connect with the error that the "URI can't be null".

Comment: Can you add what `System.out.println("URL = " + con.getURL());` you have tested this with?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem.  Have you found the cause?  I can get the URL just fine with curl, so it's not a problem on that side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing your `con.setDoOutput(true);` or setting it to `false`. That line is telling your connection that you are going to be using it to write output, but then later on you are reading from the stream by calling `con.getInputStream()`.

Comment: Sure, I fixed that, but the exception is being raised on the line above the `getInputStream` call.