# HttpURLConnection URI can't be null

Tags: java

I want to make a GET request to an website, but I get `URI can't be null.`

```
String url = "https://valid_url.com";

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url)).openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

connection.connect(); //-> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI can't be null.
```

Why I get `URI can't be null`?

P.S.: I'm using jdk10

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004977/java-uri-cant-be-null-error-on-simple-http-client) will help.

Comment: @MensurQulami I had read that, but that answer didn't help me.

Comment: Try URLConnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine.

I tested the code with this :

```
String url = "https://google.com";
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url)).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
```

May be the url you are accessing is not **GET** type. Check for that.